# Axial component identification

Tags: components, identification

Please help identify this component. It is cylindrical, with an axial configuration, and no obvious indication of which end is which. The writing on it is:
K25U
104M
50V
8502

The 104M makes me think it is a 0.1 uF capacitor, but, in my extremely limited experience, this is an unusual form factor for a capacitor. My googling for images of similar looking capacitors has turned up nothing.

[image: Photo of the component]

Answer (score 1):

I think your guess is right. From the code and appearance, it should be: an unpolarized, 100nF, ±20% tolerance (from the "M"), 50V capacitor. That form factor is not unusual for older capacitors, and the physical size makes sense for a 100nF 50V cap.

Also, if that "8502" is a date code, that would be January 1985!

To verify (or at least narrow down) whether it's a capacitor or not, you could check resistance in both directions. If there's no conductivity in either direction, it's very probably a capacitor. If not, then it's either a broken capacitor or something else entirely.

---

Edit: For completeness, a datasheet search for "K25U" turns up a couple things:

- K25UF, a 3A, 2.5kVrwm diode, axial package, from Voltage Multipliers, Inc. Highly doubt it's this.
- A series of ceramic disc capacitors, safety class X1/Y2, part no. SxxxK25U2MS6.K7. Package doesn't match.
- Semikron SK25UT, an 800V thyristor module. Definitely not that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an axial molded ceramic capacitor - 100nF +/- 20% (M) 50 V rating.

It was likely manufactured in January of 1985.

[Here](http://www.kemet.com/Lists/FileStore/Capacitor%20Selection%20Guide.pdf#page106) (page 106) you can see some similar types.

I don't see a datasheet reference to that part number on the net, but I would guess it might be Z5U dielectric from the 'U' in the part number, value/rating and the age. If so, you could expect it to be very unstable with temperature and time (and change drastically with applied voltage)